# A mechanical way of finding out any action's impact on config files

Tags: filesystem, monitoring

Is there a mechanical way to find out the impact of any action on the config files?

The action can be anything: installing a package, adding a user, turning on a service, or updating an SSH key.

For example:

- Adding a user may modify /etc/passwd, /etc/group, and /etc/shadow.
- `ssh-copy-id` may modify the authorized_keys file of the user on the server.

I understand that one advantage of Linux over Windows is that configurations are more or less in one place and subject to manual modification (e.g. manually modifying /etc/passwd etc. instead of using `useradd`).

Many online tutorials explain which config files an action may modify and how.  But I would like some mechanical way to make sure that I miss nothing.

Maybe something like dedicating a Ubuntu virtual machine to experimenting, doing the action in question, and scanning the whole machine (or only the likely directories) for change?  A scan after a `useradd` action would flag /etc/passwd etc. as having changed.

I am not necessarily asking whether anyone could come up with a how-to on the fly. Maybe there is a standard method students of Linux have always used?

Comment: You could use `installwatch`, part of the `checkinstall` package.

Comment: what do you mean by "mechanical"? "Mechanical" for me means something that involves physical mechanisms, like clocks, springs, motors, levers etc.

Comment: @raj I guess that's an English usage question? I don't mind answering. 'Mechanical' in this context means something like 'rote' or 'mindless.'